# Import table using IMPORTXML

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to pull the table from https://rotogrinders.com/schedules/nfl into Google Sheets

I tried using ImportHTML("https://rotogrinders.com/schedules/nfl", "table", 1) but it just returns the header:

Time    Team    Opponent    Line    Moneyline   Over/Under  Projected Points    Projected Points Change

Using ImportXML, I tried IMportXML("https://rotogrinders.com/schedules/nfl","//tr"), but it returns the same header and no data.

I dont think the tbody needs authentication to access. I logged out, cleared my cache and even tried on another computer and still no tbody.

I know its a table called "tschedules", but cant get the data

Is there another part of the XPATH I am missing?

This is the XPATH from google scraper: "//table[1]/tbody/tr[td]"

Comment: Consider that you need to subscribe to the relevant API rather than scrape the data from webpage

Comment: I dont see anything on the site about an API offering.  Is it something I can reverse engineer from the page source code?

Comment: No. Contact the website developers.

Comment: The content o the page seems to be loaded dynamically. Therefore, scrapping the source does not help. You need some automated UI instead, e.g. Selenium, or an API endpoint as suggested.

Answer (score -1):

When you load this website the actual table doesn't load in for a few seconds. This is why you're not seeing any data come in. If you can set some wait time on that import call somehow then it would work.

Comment: I have the ImportXML formula as A1 on my page and i have left it open for hours without the data ever populating.  One thing I find interesting is that I put another formula about 3 rows down in D1 and the A1 formula went from showing the headers to an error saying that the formula in D1 was causing the data from A1 to not be displayed. I thought it was maybe a white font, but i made sure it was black and still no data.  Also when clicking the blank cells where the data shoudl be, it doesnt show anything in the formula bar.  Is the data coming over I just cant see it?