# IMPORTXML Imported Content is Empty - See Demo Sheet

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import the **Company Profile** 'Description' from this site: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IVR

I made a [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lQi0InnnlhEi3b3AI6uee1XLtfaSnN_8DwpuM69c2KA/edit#gid=0) and all of my tries have failed (see cells **`D8`** - **`E8`**):

`=IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IVR","//*[@id='Col2-11-QuoteModule-Proxy']/div/div/div/p")`

`=IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IVR","//p[@class='businessSummary.Mt(10px).Ov(h).Tov(e)']")`

Does this have to do with the div the content is in?

On the left side of the page, I was successful in pulling in the data for **52 Week Range**.  The formula for this is in cell `G8`.

I've looked at these questions on stack and they don't look like they apply:

[Importxml Imported Content Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34217955/importxml-imported-content-empty)

[Import table using IMPORTXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52505995/import-table-using-importxml)

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option :

```
=IMPORTXML(B2;"substring-before(substring-after(//script[@id='fc'],'""longBusinessSummary"":""'),'"",""city""')")
```

[image: YahooF]

Comment: ahhh got it- had to pull from script tag.  Question - where is the id='fc' coming from ? That will help me identify other pieces I want to pull.  thanks so much

Comment: Yes, since the site relies heavily on javascript you have to pull it from there. `@id=fc` comes from the parse of the page. For example, with R, you get : https://framapic.org/KQB34BgNfnzi/VYeXuwoNLX3T.PNG You can obtain the same information with Google Sheets, but it's less convenient.

Answer (score 0):

in the meantime try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(TRANSPOSE(
 IMPORTDATA("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IVR")), 2500, 60), 
 "select Col57 limit 10 offset 2021", 0),,999), "\:""(.+?)""")
```

[image]